# Programmatically access to Amazon workdocs

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-workdocs

My company have a new requirement: users would like to have an online documents library in order to make versioning and collaborative work; at the same time they want to access/use these files via our web-application (that we already do).

We are already using Amazon S3 to store our web application files so far. And our application is powered by Amazon EC2. Therefore Amazon Workdoc seems a straightforward choice as it should seamlessly integrate with other Amazon services.

However I can't seem to find any documentation about inter integration between workdoc and S3 or EC2. The more I read about, the more it seems that these two services meet different purpose and that there is not gateway between the two of them. On the other hand OwnCloud has a way to store datas in S3 and provides basically all what Amazon Workdocs provides... And it seems weird that Amazon didn't think about this use case.

Is there a way to programmatically access files stored on Amazon via Workdoc, or to configure Workdoc to store files on a S3 bucket (that is easily accessed programmatically)? Otherwise, what are the downsides of Owncloud solution that led Amazon to NOT provide this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WorkDocs API is now generally available.

The Developer's Guide can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/developerguide/what_is.html

The API Reference is here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

You can use a CloudWatch event based upon a WorkDocs API call, such as *InitiateDocumentVersionUpload* to trigger a Lambda service to act on the WorkDocs objects.

Comment: Thank you. Almost a year later the API has developed a lot, and we are currently working on it.